# Codeigniter Fatal error: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: C:\to\tmp) in path\to\Session\Session.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I was going to install my new codeigniter project. I got the error

> Fatal error: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: 
>    C:\xampp\tmp) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Tetavendor\system\libraries\Session\Session.php 
>    on line 140

And I've found the similar question in stackoverflow
[PHP 7 user sessions issue - Failed to initialize storage module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125849/php-7-user-sessions-issue-failed-to-initialize-storage-module/43551298)

But none of the solutions worked for me. My codeigniter version is 3.0.0. So how can solve this issue?

Comment: Have you set the session save path example `$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/session/';` make sure 0700 for folder permission I would not leave it null `$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;` Then what I do is I autoload the library but you can load library in each controller you need it up to you.

Comment: "None of the solutions worked for me" is not detailed enough. You have to mention each attempt. There's no way to guess alternatives without knowing what you actually tried.

Comment: config session code `$config['sess_driver'] = 'redis';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 7200;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE`;

Comment: @user4419336 When I set  `$config['sess_save_path'] =C:\xampp\tmp` I got the same error like `Fatal error: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: C:\xampp\tmp) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Tetavendor\system\libraries\Session\Session.php on line 140.But There is a directory n tmp in xampp `.How do I solve this?

Comment: instead of redis try files

Answer (score 19):

Just add a correct path to store session.
Example : Goto config file & replace

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
```

With

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/session/';
```

Don't forget to make 0777 permission to Cache folder.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have resolved this issue by now.

In my case, my session information is stored in the database.

```
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
```

The error was actually meaning that the database, aka storage, was not accessible. In my logs under /application/logs/, it had an error

> -> Unable to connect to the database

Set the ['db_debug'] to TRUE and it will give you further tips on your particular issue.

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
```

However, maybe it is the same issue that I encountered. The database hostname as 'localhost', which was perfectly fine until I upgraded MySql to 5.7 on my Mac High Sierra 10.13.6. Switching 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' fixed the issue (for me).

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

This is from my /application/config/database.php file. I apologize if your system doesn't have the same config file. I inherited this codebase and I have never worked on another Codeigniter application before.

I do hope this helps someone.